# Monitoring production web-based applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I have several applications that are running 25 hours a day, 7-days a week. They are all web-based, saas applications running on Ruby on Rails. We host our production apps currently on Heroku.

I need a notification system to let me know when the applications are off-line. I know there are a number of options.

I've used Nagios in the past, but it's a bit too configuration intensive for what I need. Also, I'd like an application that I don't host.

Also, I have some worker instances that are running batch jobs. It might be nice to be able to monitor those as well.

It's important that the solution be able to still provide notifications even if Amazon EC2 is down -- so one based on Heroku or Engineyard probably wouldn't work.

Comment: It all depends on how much (and what kind) of monitoring you need. Just responding to HTTP/HTTPS requests? contains specific content on the page? running background jobs? ... all are possible, but depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the question -- Mainly, I need Up/Down status. It might be useful for that to be able to authenticate and look at logged in pages. It might be also useful to see content on some pages to look at data integrity. Batch job monitoring (we use resque/redis) would be nice, but not required. Main thing is simple and reliable at this point.

Comment: from where do you burrow `1 Hour` everyday? I need it too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, based on your initial need --- I would go with either for heroku monitoring. Neither requires SSH to install

- http://www.uptimerobot.com/ (checks and emails you when page is not responding) ... I use this and it works well
- New Relic Availability http://newrelic.com/features/availability-monitoring --- if you're already using new-relic, just turn this on.

Comment: Does New Relic Server Monitoring work with Heroku? I've googled and checked both New Relic and Heroku and can't seem to find a straight answer. Uptime Robot looks awesome and it looks like it is spread across multiple EC2 zones http://blog.uptimerobot.com/better-accuracy-with-multi-continent-monitoring-new-ips/ .

Comment: I wondered the same thing when I first saw the list of platform types: `Ubuntu or Debian`, `Red Hat or CentOS`, `Other Linux (glibc 2.5 or newer)`, and `Windows`.. but I then figured that *Server Monitoring* doesn't apply to Heroku because you're supposed to "forget servers". Plus there's the fact that Heroku is entirely based in cloud infrastructure.. so it doesn't make sense to do *server monitor* (and worry about stuff like disks, etc.) Definitely do the full range of *app monitoring* and *availability monitoring*.

Answer (score 1):

For your worker instances that are running as batch jobs, look at http://www.pushmon.com. You just need to call a URL whenever your batch jobs run successfully. Note I'm associated with PushMon.

We use UptimeRobot for website monitoring.